# Local buffer databases

Tags: database, postgresql, buffer

I am new to using databases. I have a very basic question that I am unable to comprehend. What is the difference between a local buffer and a global buffer? So, if I am accessing a database, I am accessing a local buffer, is it? Any examples to explain the above would be good. Does it have to do with different clients accessing the same database or same client accessing different sessions of the database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not a basic question. This issue of **local buffer** or **global buffer** is never mentioned in the context of casual use of a database. If I google _"local buffer" postgresql_ ,the first result is your own question, which is a good indicator that it's an uncommon topic. Would you share where you've read/heard about these buffers?

Comment: Neither of those are terms of art in PostgreSQL.  I assume "global buffer" corresponds to shared_buffers and local buffer corresponds to temp_buffers; but "local buffer" could also mean blocks within the temp files used for sorts and hash joins.

Comment: Ok, I will go with it. Thanks though!